# Angular 4 Core Module, why there are two provider arrays

Tags: angular

I was looking at the official angular documentation about NgModule (https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#configure-core-services-with-coremoduleforroot)
and in the example provided at the end of the page there's the file core.module.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf }       from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }      from '@angular/common';
import { TitleComponent }    from './title.component';
import { UserService }       from './user.service';
import { UserServiceConfig } from './user.service';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ TitleComponent ],
  exports:      [ TitleComponent ],
  providers:    [ UserService ]
})
export class CoreModule {

  constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error(
        'CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
    }
  }

  static forRoot(config: UserServiceConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: CoreModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: UserServiceConfig, useValue: config }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

This is a Core Module, and by using the constructor and the forRoot method 
we're sure the core module is imported only once, and we have only one instance of the services provided.

- What's the difference between the providers array in the @NgModule({...}) and the providers array in the method forRoot?
- Should I provide my singleton services in the @NgModel section or in the Core Module?

Answer (score 2):

`forRoot` is used for creating singletons.

You should be calling `forRoot()` on the root level only (AppModule).

With this structure:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    exports: [],
    providers: []

})
export class I18nModule {
    static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: I18nModule,
            providers: [I18nService, UserConfig]
        };
    }
}
```

You will have to import `I18nModule` (just an example) like this in `AppModule`:

```
I18nModule.forRoot()
```

And like this in the rest of imports:

```
imports: [I18nModule]
```

Basically, on the `AppModule` import you are instancing singletons of the services that are in the `providers` of the `forRoot()` imported module. This allows you to always reference the same instance instead of having several instances of the same service.

**Why 2 providers arrays:**

In your question, the first array could perfectly be empty, adding all your providers into your `forRoot()` `providers` array. So you could:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ TitleComponent ],
  exports:      [ TitleComponent ],
  providers:    []
})
export class CoreModule {

  constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    if (parentModule) {
      throw new Error(
        'CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
    }
  }

  static forRoot(config: UserServiceConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: CoreModule,
      providers: [
        UserService,
        {provide: UserServiceConfig, useValue: config }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

- You should provide your singleton services in your `CoreModule` and import it with `forRoot()` in your `AppModule`
- If you are using `forRoot()`, add your providers in your `forRoot` method

Comment: What is userServiceConfig useful for?

Comment: @Moshe for handling user's configuration. Usually this would mean that `UserServiceConfig` extends a `UserService` class. Check this: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#configure-core-services-with-coremoduleforroot

Comment: How would this work in a production setting? current setup: I'm using localstorage to store JWT token - in which provides username, name, etc.

Comment: When you have your token you can query your BE or API in `UserServiceConfig` service in order to get user's information. If I can give you my point of view, don't follow the localstorage approach, it stores permanently the token and the access information. Cookies or seasons are better for this imho..

Comment: Tokens expire after 3 days, and my site doesn't need any more security than that for now. Still don't understand Angular's docs :/

Answer (score 2):

> This is a Core Module, and by using the constructor and the forRoot method we're sure the core module is imported only once, and we have only one instance of the services provided.

Technically it doesn't ensure that it's only once. The constructor throws an error if there is a duplicate. Resolving the duplicate error becomes the developer's responsibility, and sometimes that can be difficult.

> What's the difference between the providers array in the @NgModule({...}) and the providers array in the method forRoot?

The `@NgModule` creates metadata that is attached to the `CoreModule` class. Angular uses this metadata to load the module. The `forRoot` is a function which returns metadata as an array. That means you don't have the help of a decorator to format that array and have to do it manually.

The `providers` in the `forRoot` declare that a dependency symbol is associated with a value. That value is passed to the function as a parameter.

You can actually do this with `@NgModule` and get the same result.

```
 let config = new UserServiceConfig(); // <-- create instance here.

 @NgModule({
     imports:      [ CommonModule ],
     declarations: [ TitleComponent ],
     exports:      [ TitleComponent ],
     providers:    [ 
         UserService,
         {provide: UserServiceConfig, useValue: config }
     ]
 })
```

The above does the same thing as `forRoot()` but it introduces two problems.

- the above code could be executed more than once
- how would a module know what configuration it needs?

> Should I provide my singleton services in the @NgModel section or in the Core Module?

I want to say that there are no singletons in Angular. That's because the dependency injection tree doesn't support such a classification of a provider. To get around this limitation we add this `forRoot` trick to declare a provider *only once* for *one particular import*.

This is the key to understanding how this works. We're not altering what is provided. We are altering what is **imported**.

It means that we want only *one module* to *import* this service. It's assumed that the module doing the importing is only loaded once. Therefore, this creates a singleton of that provider.

What's important is that your **main** module call `forRoot()` in it's `imports` section, and this function is only used once.

The tutorial you read uses this technique to create only *one* provider of a config object of type `UserServiceConfig`. You can then inject this type into your other objects.